# S3 not allow to view and modify bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, bucket

How can I prevent users that have the ability to write and read to/from S3 buckets to see the content of bucket policy and modify it?

There are a few users that have explicitly denied write to the bucket and I do not want them to look in policy and find out who can or even modify it.

What would be an action for view or modify bucket policy?

Comment: Please Edit your question to include the permissions that have been granted to these users and also the Bucket Policy (if relevant).

Answer (score 1):

Permissions required to update bucket ACL / policies are: `s3:PutBucketAcl`, `s3:PutBucketPolicy`. For objects it is `s3:PutObjectAcl`.

For viewing bucket policies: `s3:GetBucketAcl` and `s3:GetBucketPolicy`.